azure devops dont talk the latest flutter veriosn , and when build show this error
azure always make flutter verison 2.2.1. assume i add in the yaml file to take the latest verison ,and then it shows error when build:
 ##[error]Error: Failed cd: cd: no such file or directory: D:\a\1\s\Naadel\src\flutter\naadel
i add this yaml file  # release number which is increment
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
  - pipelines/production
  - pipelines/demo

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  PROJECT_DIRECTORY: "Naadel/src/flutter/naadel"
  FLUTTER_VERSION: 3.19.3  # Assuming you don't need a custom version

stages:
  - stage: 'Build_Android'
    displayName: Build_Android_Version

    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: BuildingAndroid
        steps:
          - task: aloisdeniel.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0  # Using aloisdeniel's extension
            displayName: 'Flutter installing'
            inputs:
              mode: 'auto'
              channel: 'stable'
              verison: 'latest'

         
          - task: aloisdeniel.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0  # Using aloisdeniel's extension
            inputs:
              target: "apk"
              projectDirectory: "$(PROJECT_DIRECTORY)"
              entryPoint: "lib/main.dart"
              iosCodesign: false
              buildNumber: "$(Build.BuildNumber)" # You can use a variable here if needed.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I can reproduce the same error with your sample yaml.
It uses flutter verison 2.2.1 because you specify stable & latest version on Flutter Install task. The aloisdeniel.flutter extension is old, last maintained on 5/4/2021. You can use Hey24sheep.flutter extesion instead, it's the copy one and maintained recently.
The lastest stable flutter version with Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0 is 3.19.6, if you would like 3.19.3, specify the version as below:
      - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0
        inputs:
          mode: 'auto'
          channel: 'stable'
          version: 'custom'
          customVersion: '$(FLUTTER_VERSION)'


For the error ##[error]Error: Failed cd: cd: no such file or directory: D:\a\1\s\Naadel\src\flutter\naadel, this is because you don't have such directory Naadel\src\flutter\naadel in your repository or directory path is not correct.
the projectDirectory value should points to the path which contains the pubspec.yaml.

Please check your repo structure, make sure you have Naadel\src\flutter\naadel which contains pubspec.yaml.
For example, my pubspec.yaml is in the root directory of repository, i can speicify $(system.defaultworkingdirectory) for the projectDirectory.

My sample yaml:
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

variables:
  PROJECT_DIRECTORY: "$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)"
  FLUTTER_VERSION: 3.19.3  # Assuming you don't need a custom version

stages:
- stage: 'Build_Android' 
  displayName: Build_Android_Version
  jobs:
    - job: Build 
      displayName: BuildingAndroid 
      steps:
      - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0
        inputs:
          mode: 'auto'
          channel: 'stable'
          version: 'custom'
          customVersion: '$(FLUTTER_VERSION)'

      - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0 # Using aloisdeniel's extension 
        inputs: 
          target: "apk" 
          projectDirectory: "$(PROJECT_DIRECTORY)"
          entryPoint: "lib/main.dart" 
          iosCodesign: false 
          buildNumber: "$(Build.BuildNumber)" # You can use a variable here if needed .


thank you the issues was sloved, but i face another issue which is Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. It's likely that this file was generated under D:\a\1\s\src\Flutter\Naadel\build, but the tool couldn't find it.   how can i solve it? i am using flavor and i add it to the yaml file @wade zhou - MSFT

Thanks for your update, and glad to know it's resolved! Regarding the new issue Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file, let's track on your new ticket as it's a different query. In addition, please share build.gradle content and more debug log for troubleshooting. Glad to help.
